# extract all pixel values from a raster record to put in another table

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a table that is built with PostGIS Raster and has some raster record. I want to extract all the pixels and pixel values and put it in another table. for example if one the raster size is 300*400 the resulting table will have 120000 records with pixel location and pixel values. Any one has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I realize it has been awhile, but if anyone comes across this, you could probably do something similar to this: [Postgres/Postgis - Querying all values in clipped raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981411/postgres-postgis-querying-all-values-in-clipped-raster/20007789#20007789) without doing the clip.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting, please try to include all or most of the required information directly in your question or answer. Relying on external links is bad because over time links get broken.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.  Although I did link to another Stack Overflow page :-)