# Postgres/Postgis - Querying all values in clipped raster

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis

I'm currently using Postgres 9.1

My goal is to clip a PostGIS raster with a polygon.  Then I would like either an postgres array or delimited set of values for each of the raster pixels that are contained within that polygon. Here is the query I have gotten so far:

```
SELECT  p.gid, (ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(r.rast, p.geom))).value AS fval
FROM temp_raster AS r, temp_shapefile AS p
WHERE (r.start_time = 1384516800) 
GROUP BY gid, fval;
```

This will output:

```
 gid | fcstval 
-----+---------
   1 |       0
   1 |       2
   2 |       0
   2 |       2
   3 |       5
   4 |       0
   4 |       1
   4 |       2
   4 |       3
   4 |       5
```

This data is good, but I would like a set of values for each gid like this:

```
 gid |  fcstval 
-----+----------
   1 |       0,2
   2 |       0,2
   3 |         5
   4 | 0,1,2,3,5
```

The trouble I'm having is trying to then get these values aggregated into either an array or delimited string.  Here's my attempt at an array:

```
SELECT  p.gid, array_agg((ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(r.rast, p.geom))).value) AS fval
FROM temp_raster AS r, temp_shapefile AS p
WHERE (r.start_time = 1384516800)
GROUP BY gid;
```

This doesn't work, and provides the error:

```
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

My guess is this is because I can't call array_agg in this way.  I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to do this otherwise.  A subquery perhaps? I haven't been able to come up with anything yet though to get this working.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out for arrays.  If I want it in a string, I can just convert my array to a string.   However if anyone has any suggestions of cleaning this up I would appreciate it, as this doesn't seem like the simplest markup

```
SELECT p.gid, array_agg((subquery).tempval) as fcstval 
FROM pih_raster AS r, hwy_pih_vertex_buf AS p, 
( 
    SELECT p.gid AS tempgid, (ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(r.rast, p.geom))).value AS tempval 
    FROM pih_raster AS r, hwy_pih_vertex_buf AS p 
    WHERE (r.start_time <= 1384624800) GROUP BY tempgid, tempval
) AS subquery
WHERE (r.start_time <= 1384624800) AND ((subquery).tempgid = gid) GROUP BY p.gid;
```

Here's the output:

```
 gid |   fcstval   
-----+-------------
   1 | {0,2}
   2 | {0,2}
   3 | {5}
   4 | {0,1,2,3,5}
```